# Make iPhone use speaker for calls when charging

Tags: magsafe, speakers

I have a few MagSafe charging stands (with phone vertically oriented), and I expected that iPhone would automatically pick speaker mode rather than assuming I'd be holding the phone against my ear.

Is there a way to configure the iPhone to assume that when it's on the charging stand to always select Speaker when it's charging?

Update: I already had *Auto-Select Speaker in Call* enabled which seems like it should do what I want automatically, but doesn't

Comment: Under *Accessibility → Audio → Auto-Select Speaker in Call* should be turned on.  This setting will automatically select the speaker when you're not holding the phone to your ear.  How is the charger placed? Vertically or horizontally (flat), or somewhere in between?

Answer (score 1):

Although this may not entirely answer the question (in fact, maybe not at all) since it will probably not allow you to specify the kind of loudspeaker on the iPhone, I still want to share it since it may lead you to a solution that works for you anyway.

In the Shortcuts app, you can determine whether the iPhone is connected to a charger and then select a playback destination to iPhone, headphones, TVs, HomePods, etc.

[image]